# How Do I Reset the Sharing & Permission Setting on a MacBook?

Tags: macos, finder, permission, filesystem

[image]

When you select the "Get Info" option, the mac will bring up a pop-up with the various attributes of the object selected. In the "Sharing & Permissions" section, you can set the access level.

I switched my hard-disk (MacIntosh HD) to no access, thinking that no one else except me has access. But I am getting locked out too. Right now, all I have is a black screen with the pointer. How do I get back access to the hard-drive?  Please note that the image above is taken from a network computer as reference.  It is my personal computer that I cannot get to.

Comment: When is your last backup? Does your Mac support internet recovery or have a recovery HD? Please edit that detail into the post. The recovery steps differ if you have a CD to do installation or can use Apple's recovery tools to reinstall your OS. Lastly, did you propagate those permissions to all files or just change one item?

Comment: Assuming you're not running OS X 10.11, Have you tried booting to Recovery Mode and Repair Disk Permissions with Disk Utility?

Comment: Did you assign it to all three names? And to all subsequent items (using the gear)?

Comment: This is a macbook model A1342, which I later updated to run El Capitan.  Let me check if my school library has any rebooting tool.  Meanwhile, please kindly advise if you have any alternative.  Also, I changed the setting for "everyone".  Thanks ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further review it may be best to use a recovery to fix this issue.

Comment: Let me know if this works or not. If not there are a couple other things you can try before reverting to your latest backup as that can be time consuming

Comment: 777 is not the correct permissions for `/` nor would I set it to it either!  Also you must always escape spaces with a backslash or quote the name that contains spaces.  `sudo chmod 777 MacIntosh HD` is plain wrong!

Comment: I would not suggest keeping it set to this but just to gain control until I can reset to something else. What permission would you suggest?

Comment: The default permissions on `/` i.e. are `0755` and owned by `root:admin`, e.g., on my system that hasn't been mucked with: `drwxr-xr-x   36 root  admin     1292 Dec 12 12:25 .`

Comment: For whatever reason, MacBook could not sign into iTunes for an online recovery.  So, I took it down to an Apple store.  I was lucky this time, the tech gal got access to the hard-disk and switched back the permission.  But if it did not work, she would need to wipe out my computer ....

Comment: Did she happen to explain how she did so? I doubt she would but it's worth asking.

Comment: She went into disk utility with her Apple credential.  Unfortunately, it's not something you or I can do.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted without losing anything!